# How to add "error codes" to result?

Tags: php, android, mysql, json, error-handling

I know how to get a value, a single row or multiple rows from a MySQL-Database to my Android-App through JSON. But how can I add a value to the result, which tells me whether the query was okay or not, and while not, add something like error codes?

This is my Code right now:
PHP

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT Role, age FROM table1");
$json = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $json[] = $row;
}
mysqli_close($con);
print json_encode($json);
```

Android

```
        try{
            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
            for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
               JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
               Log.i("log_tag","age: " + json_data.getString("age") +
                              ", role: "+json_data.getString("Role"));
            }
        }
        catch(JSONException e){
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
        }
```

Now, for example, the query is not successful, if there aren't any users in the database.
In that case I want to get an error that something is wrong and something like error codes which tell me, what is actually wrong. Otherwise i get an "OK-Message" and the result.
How can I do that?

I know for that example i could do that simple by counting the values in the android app but i need that for something more complex like errors in a registration form.

I hope you understand what i mean :)
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*First*, **define the JSON schema/structure** - which is part of API and the contract *should* be documented. After that most everything will "fit in place" and it becomes an exercise in basic programming.

For example consider this *contract* definition;

```
{
   status:         - string of "success" or "fail"
   errorMessage:   - optional, an error message
   results: [..]   - array of results (always empty on non-OK status), where
                   -   each result is an array of the form [role, age]
}
```

Then create the JSON result to *fit* the contract;

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT Role, age FROM table1");

$resp = array();
if ($result) {
  // Good, also add results
  $resp["status"] = "success";

  $results = array();
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $results[] = $row;
  }
  $resp["results"] = $results;
} else {
  // No good!
  $resp["status"] = "fail";

  $resp["errorMessage"] = "Database query failed";
  // Or if this is desired to be exposed (only for development!)
  // $resp["errorMessage"] = mysqli_error($con);

  // No results, but keep empty JSON array to make JSON access more consistent
  $resp["results"] = array();       
}
mysqli_close($con);

print json_encode($resp);
```

Then update the the Android client to accept this new JSON structure. It needs to be adapted to include an additional level, first checking for `status` (is it "success"?). If it is OK, use the `results` array. If not display `errorMessage` or otherwise inform the user of the issue. Also note that a query can be a "success" even though no results were returned.

The *only* time an exception should be thrown is if the JSON is *incorrectly* handled - everything else should be handled with appropriate value checking and conditionals.

Answer (score 0):

A try...catch block will work nicely with that.

http://php.net/manual/en/internals2.opcodes.catch.php

Comment: [Link-only answers aren't desirable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).